# How to rank DataFrame by subgroup

Tags: python, pandas

If I have a DataFrame such as

```
  col1   col2  col3
0   x1  typeA     3
1   x2  typeB    13
2   x3  typeB     3
3   x4  typeA     5
4   x5  typeB     1
5   x6  typeA     1
```

is there a way of ranking the rows by col3 for each type in col2? For example this solution would look like

```
  col1   col2  col3  rank
0   x1  typeA     3    2
1   x2  typeB    13    1
2   x3  typeB     3    2 
3   x4  typeA     5    1
4   x5  typeB     1    3
5   x6  typeA     1    3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`transform` keeps the same shape as your original dataframe.  Then use a `lambda` function to rank `col3` based on groupings from `col2`..

```
df['col4'] = df.groupby('col2').col3.transform(lambda group: group.rank())

>>> df
  col1   col2  col3  col4
0   x1  typeA     3     2
1   x2  typeB    13     3
2   x3  typeB     3     2
3   x4  typeA     5     3
4   x5  typeB     1     1
5   x6  typeA     1     1
```

Comment: i think it can be done without lambda function: `.groupby('col2').col3.transform('rank').astype(np.int8)`

Comment: @MaxU I tried that too, but the results are different.